# Output formatting of HTML parsed data

Tags: powershell, formatting

I am trying to grab some data from a inventory website page of multiple computers (hence multple pages). s.txt represents list of computers.

```
$result = @()

Get-Content C:\temp\s.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $result += Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://testurl.com/prod/hostdetails.php?qs=$($_)" -UseDefaultCredentials


    $data = $result.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName("header") |
            select -ExpandProperty InnerText
    $vhost = $data.Split([Environment]::NewLine)

    $vdata = $result.ParsedHtml.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('installedSoftwareContainer') |
             Select-Object -ExpandProperty InnerText
    $vver = ($vdata.Split([Environment]::NewLine) |
            Select-String -Pattern "Citrix 7.15 LTSR CU1" |
            Out-String)
} 

$vhost,$vver
```

Using the above code, I am able to get output but in a non-formatted way which is not helpful.

Tried using

```
Format-List -View $vhost,$vver
```

But I keep getting

```
Format-List : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'
required by parameter 'View'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\testbed.ps1:22 char:19
+ Format-List -View $vhost, $vout
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Format-List], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatListCommand
```

When I checked `$vhost | gm` and `$vver | gm` both return as `System.String`. Unsure where I am handling it wrong. All I need is `$vver` and the hostname which is either `$vhost` or which is grabbed by `$_` in $result.

Comment: `$result` is an ever-growing collection through the use of `+=`. You are retrieving data from that collection during each loop iteration. That is not standard. I would set your `Invoke-Webrequest` to another variable (that will be overwritten with a single object during each iteration) if you are planning to use that **one** output throughout the iteration.

Comment: Better yet, if you do not need `$results` outside of this loop at all, just change `+=` to `=` and things will become better. `$results` will be a collection and return type `object[]` rather than `object`. After the first iteration, it will start returning collections of objects.

Comment: The pipeline automatically unrolls arrays, so `Get-Member` will show you the type of the elements if the input is an array. Use `gm $vhost` or `gm $vver` to see the type of the original object. Also, `Format-List -View` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. Use `$vhost, $vver | Format-List` to get the value(s) of those variables displayed in list format.